# How to make my tile system work with pygame in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, 2d, tiles

Im making a custom tile system for my game. Its my first time and didnt expect to go that far without a tutorial. So i did my best and made something that works when i render in a tile with the `blit` method but when i use `pygame.sprite.Sprite` sprites it doesnt work. I need it to be with pygame's sprite system because it makes it easier doing other stuff and im positive its a rookie mistake i just cant find it.

Code:

```
# Importing libraries
try: 
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    from time import *
    from os import *
    from random import *
    import sys
    print("All Libraries imported successfully \n")
except :
    print("Error while importing modules and libraries")
    sys.exit()
    
# Creating Screen

screen_width = 640
screen_height = 640
tile_size = int(screen_width / 10)
screen_res = (screen_width, screen_height)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running_fps = 144

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_res)
pygame.display.set_caption(f"GTA Circuit Hack FPS:{running_fps}, {screen_width} x {screen_height}, Tile Size: {tile_size}")

# Loading images

#    Background image:
backgroundImg = pygame.image.load("Background.png")
backgroundImg = pygame.transform.scale(backgroundImg, screen_res)

#    Not walkable tile image:
noWalkTileImg = pygame.image.load("unwalkTile.png")
noWalkTileImg = pygame.transform.scale(noWalkTileImg, (tile_size, tile_size))

# making tiles

tiles = []
tile_y = 0
tile_x = 0
for i in range(10):
    
    if i > 0:
        tile_y += tile_size
        
    
    for i in range(10):
        if i > 0:
            tile_x += tile_size
            
            
        tiles.append((tile_x, tile_y))
    tile_x = 0
    
tile_x = 0
tile_y = 0
        
# creating object classes

class BadTile (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, tile):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = noWalkTileImg
        self.tile = tile
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = self.tile[0]
        self.y = self.tile[1]  
        
    def update(self):
        self.x = self.tile[0]
        self.y = self.tile[1]  

# creating objects

tile1 = BadTile(tiles[99])
game_tiles = pygame.sprite.Group()
game_tiles.add(tile1)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(running_fps)
    screen.blit(backgroundImg, (0,0))

    # rendering
    
    game_tiles.update()
    game_tiles.draw(screen)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
print ("Exited with no errors")
sys.exit()
```

Images:
[image] [image]

Comment: I basically made a list with all tiles with a nested for loop and normally i put the number of the tile i want and it contains a tuple with coordinates. But when i put `tile[99]` which is supposed to be the bottom right tile, the light green tile is on the top left tile (`tile[0]`)

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The latter delegates to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) — you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group. [...]

The former uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects — you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

So you need to set `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y`. Instead of `self.x` and `self.y`. You don't need `self.x` and `self.y` at all:

```py
class BadTile (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, tile):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = noWalkTileImg
        self.tile = tile
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.tile[0]
        self.rect.y = self.tile[1]  
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x = self.tile[0]
        self.rect.y = self.tile[1]
```

Comment: I made so many games using pygame's sprite method and yet still, a small "rect." error caught me. Thank you very much for your help